# Refuelling an airbus to maximum

Tags: aircraft-design

The airbus A350 aircraft when being refuelled seems to drop when the wings are filled.How  much is the drop from empty to full.Thankyou

Comment: Are you asking how much the wing tips drop, or how much the entire aircraft drops?

Answer (score -1):

That’s going to depend on a lot of things including how well serviced the struts are, what the existing payload on the aircraft is and whether the aircraft is parked on any sort of grade.

I don’t work the A350, but I work other heavy aircraft and I’ve had them “settle” quite a bit when putting on a full fuel load.